# Spring State Machine Modelling Tool Support in Intellij

Tags: intellij-plugin, spring-statemachine, papyrus

I have just migrated from Eclipse to Intellij [*we can use this only now*].

We are having lot of Spring State Machine Model Diagrams (https://spring.io/projects/spring-statemachine) created via Papyrus Plugin  (https://www.eclipse.org/papyrus/) in eclipse that needs to be imported in intellij Ide

But in intellij I am not finding any support for Eclipse Papyrus, neither do I find any other plugin that I can use as an alternative to Papyrus in Intellij.

Any help or guidance is highly welcomed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: No not till now...I guess Papyrus was designed only for Eclipse

Comment: Ok thanks! Btw how complex/easy is it to use this framework? We have a fairly complex application we are looking to implement. There a lot of state changes so may evaluate this.

Comment: I do have fair experience on this tool..and it is really very good tool..In my company we use it for entire order flow, customer complain flow, cms flow and what not